# Posting to facebook page wall via curl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I am trying to post to my facebook page wall using curl but i keep getting the following error

```
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

How do i generate the correct access token using curl? if you go to this url http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I can then put in the following https://graph.facebook.com/337588736279406/feed and this will show my wall feed i can then change this to post and add a field for the message content if i then run this i get the following response.

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorised the application to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

What do i have to do to authorize me as a user??

Can someone help me on this.

```
    <?php

function postify($arr) {
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    return rtrim($fields_string, '&');
}


$appid = 'app id';
$redirect_url = 'http://stickynote.users36.interdns.co.uk';
$app_secret = 'app secret';
$page_id = '337588736279406';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='.$appid.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&perms=publish_stream');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$output = explode("=", $output);

curl_close($ch);

$postdata = array(
    'message' => 'this is a test message',
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed?access_token='.$output[1].'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postify($postdata));
$check = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($check);        

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to post content you must grant `publish_stream` permission to your application.

Requesting permissions can be done using [OAuth Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

BTW, If you just need it for user for testing purposes you may use Explorer Tool by choosing your application, clicking *Get Access Token* and checking needed permissions.

**Update:**
You will not be able to post on behalf of app, only user or page with appropriate `access_token` (for page it will require `manage_pages` and `access_token` from `accounts` connection of `user`).
No need to specify `perms` in `access_token` retrieval URL. Permissions should be granted before that step.

Comment: how do i do this could you help

Comment: hi juicy thanks for the responses i am abit confused to how i return the access token via curl i can run what you said http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday,publish_stream&client_id=277938122277013&redirect_uri=http://stickynote.users36.interdns.co.uk&response_type=token this will then return me with the code in the url how do i then access this via curl

Comment: You will not be able to get all this done using only curl due to need of user interaction in browser...

Comment: ah right ok so their is no way to auto post to a page feed via curl

Comment: Only if you authorize user and grant permissions before ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a page access token to do that.

In the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) it says:

> **Page access_token**
>
> An access_token used to manage a page. This is used
> when you want to perform an operation acting as a Page. This access
> token is retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts or to
> /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission. Getting
> /USER_ID/accounts will return a list of Pages (including app profile
> pages) to which the user has administrative access in addition to an
> access_token for each Page. Alternatively, you can get a page access
> token for a single, specific, page by issuing an HTTP GET to
> /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission (you
> must ask for the access_token field specifically via the fields=
> parameter). See the documentation for the Page object for more
> information

After you get the access token you can then make those api calls.

Comment: 1. You only need this if you want post as page itself, it's not required to post as a user. 2. You will need to request `publish_stream` to able to post content.